Distance between a point and a subset convex of $\mathbb{R}^n$
I want to prove this proposition:

Let $C \subset$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ convex. If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_0 \in C$ such that
$$d(x, C) = \lVert x-x_0 \rVert $$
then
$$\left\langle x-x_0,y-x_0\right\rangle \leq \ 0$$
for all $y \in C$.

I tried to prove this by contradiction. I suppose that there is $y \in C$ such that
$$\left\langle x-x_0,y-x_0 \right\rangle >0. $$
Then, as $C$ is convex, $v=\frac{1}{2}x_0+\frac{1}{2}y \in C$. I would like that $\lVert x-x_0 \rVert > \lVert x-v \rVert$, generating a contradiction, but it doesn't works.

You should probably use full convexity--that is, for each $t\in[0,1]$ and each $u,v\in C,$ $$tu+(1-t)v\in C.$$ Right now, you're only using midpoint convexity. I also suspect that orthogonal projection would be very useful, based on considering the 2-dimensional case.

Hint: Consider $v=x_0+\dfrac{\left\langle x-x_0,y-x_0 \right\rangle}{\left\langle y-x_0,y-x_0 \right\rangle}(y-x_0)$.

Suppose there is $y_0\in C$ such that $\left\langle x-x_0, y_0-x_0 \right\rangle>0$, and let $r=\frac{\left\langle x-x_0, y_0-x_0 \right\rangle}{\left\langle y_0-x_0, y_0-x_0 \right\rangle }>0$.
Since $d(x, C) = \lVert x-x_0 \rVert$, we also have $\left\langle x-y_0, x-y_0\right\rangle\geq \left\langle x-x_0, x-x_0\right\rangle$.
For the sake of simplicity, let $a=x-x_0$ and $b= y_0-x_0$. Therefore, $\left\langle a, b \right\rangle>0$ and $\left\langle a-b, a-b \right\rangle\geq\left\langle a, a \right\rangle$.
These last two inequalities imply that $\left\langle b, b \right\rangle\geq 2\left\langle a, b \right\rangle>\left\langle a, b \right\rangle$, so $$0<r=\frac{\left\langle a, b \right\rangle}{\left\langle b, b \right\rangle}<1.$$
Now, since $C$ is convex, $x_1=x_0+r(y_0-x_0)\in C$.
On the other hand,
$$
\begin{split}
\left\langle x_1-x, x_1-x_0 \right\rangle &=\left\langle x_0-x+r(y_0-x_0), r(y_0-x_0) \right\rangle\\
&=r\left\langle x_0-x, y_0-x_0 \right\rangle + r\left\langle x-x_0, y_0-x_0 \right\rangle\\
&=0.
\end{split}
$$
This last equality implies that
$$
\lVert x-x_0 \rVert^2 = \lVert x-x_1 \rVert^2 + \lVert x_1-x_0 \rVert^2>\lVert x-x_1 \rVert^2,
$$
which contradicts $d(x, C) = \lVert x-x_0 \rVert$.
